# Adding a condition to this group by statement

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a table consisting of First Name, Last Name, and Date, like this:

```
 _________
| People  |____________________________________
|----------------------------------------------|
| first_name  |  last_name  |  date            |
|----------------------------------------------|
| Jerry          Garcia      01/01/2001        |
| Adam           Garcia      01/02/2001        |
| Hans           Fist        01/02/2001        | 
| Lucy           Fist        01/02/2001        |
|______________________________________________|
```

And I have a group by and order by statement like this:

```
$this->db->group_by("date, last_name");
$this->db->order_by('date ASC');
```

So naturally, you would expect it to only give you one row for the two Garcia's and one row for the two Fist's. What I'd like to do, and keep this in mind this is a very simplified case, is to group by last name, but if `last_name = 'Garcia'` *DONT*. So you'd see both garcias and only one fist in the result set.

How do I do this?

If only it were as simple as `GROUP BY date, last_name NOT 'Garcia'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution myself. For anyone who finds themselves in a similar situation, just use a `CASE/WHEN` statement in the `SELECT` portion of your query.

You can use that as a boolean flag on each row to group by.

```
CASE `last_name` WHEN 'Garcia' THEN '1' END AS is_garcia
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can add to your first query something like

```
WHERE name != 'Garcia'
```

And then, do

```
UNION SELECT * WHERE name = 'Garcia'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get rid of the `GROUP BY` and just use `ORDER BY last_name DESC, date ASC`.

Note that if you have a specific problem you are trying to solve, post that with the question. You'll get a much better answer!

Comment: I simplified my test case and posted the most specific problem imaginable. What are you talking about? Your solution will not work because `ORDER BY` is not `GROUP BY`. I did mention how I wanted the Fist's to be grouped. Just not the Garcia's.

Comment: @ChrisG Sorry, I didn't get that you wanted both Garcia's and only one Fist. Pre-coffee help fail!

Comment: The main reason I mentioned posting a specific problem is so we can get the context that you are working in and might be able to provide alternative (maybe non-sql) answers.

Comment: No problems. I have several non-SQL answers myself, but I asked this question on Stack to avoid having to seek out a non-SQL solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditions on the `GROUP BY` clause using `HAVING`. You can then join two result sets using the `UNION` keyword.

Comment: If I do that, it will eliminate Garcias from the result set entirely. I still want them there, I just don't want them 'combined' by the group by statement.